# cambiar icono de carga wordpress

Tags: wordpress

alquien sabe como cambiar este icono de carga? o como podria buscarlo por nombre, no he encontrado informacion al respecto.
esto es wordpress

[image: icono de carga en wordpress]

Comment: Revisa tu código fuente. Si no sabes cómo encontrar el elemento entonces comparte en la pregunta el código que produce dicho icono.

Comment: no se como se llama el icono sino lo buscaria en el codigo fuente de wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en chrome, presiona f12, luego presiona la flecha que esta en rojo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego señala la imagen que quieres cambiar y ve la ruta. Al tener la ruta puedes entrar por el ftp y cambiar la imagen por la que quieras